# Rake db:migrate error while upgrade from rails2 to rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-2

I have upgrade rails2 to rails3 and when i try to rake db:migrate I have found following error

```
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)

** Invoke environment (first_time)

** Execute environment

DEPRECATION WARNING: The InstanceMethods module inside ActiveSupport::Concern will be no longer included automatically. Please define instance methods directly in ActiveSupport::Callbacks instead. (called from include at /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3214/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:29)

** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)

** Execute db:load_config

** Execute db:migrate

rake aborted!

/home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/trace_output.rb:16:in `block in trace_on': invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII (ArgumentError)

    from /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/trace_output.rb:14:in `map'

    from /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/trace_output.rb:14:in `trace_on'

    from /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:340:in `trace'

    from /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:187:in `display_error_message'

    from /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3214/gems/airbrake-3.1.14/lib/airbrake/rake_handler.rb:23:in `display_error_message_with_airbrake'

    from /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:174:in `rescue in standard_exception_handling'

    from /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'

    from /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'

    from /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.1.0/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'

    from /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/bin/rake:19:in `load'

    from /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'

    from /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3214/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'

    from /home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3214/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Comment: add entire error stack

Comment: please see above i have add entire trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error is due to non ascii characters in some of your db/migration file(s).
add

```
#encoding: utf-8
```

to the file(s) where u see strange characters

Comment: Thank you the problem was solved by adding #encoding utf8 in migration file but i found another error can you please help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19564397/undefined-method-mysql-connection-for-activerecordbaseclass

Answer (score 0):

It seems like an encoding error

add these below lines to environment.rb file and run migration

```
Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8
```

Comment: Are you getting the same error which you have posted even after using UTF_8 ?

Comment: Yes I am getting same error. I have added above line in config/environment.rb file.
I have upgrade the app from rails2 to rails3.2.14

Comment: Hope you have taken all the precautions to update from rails 2 to 3.
[this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/225-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-1) might be helpful

Comment: Yes I have follow all instruction app running successfully, but rake db:migrate give me error

Comment: Thank you the problem was solved by adding #encoding utf8 in migration file but i found another error can you please help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19564397/undefined-method-mysql-connection-for-activerecordbaseclass