# undefined method `mysql_connection' for ActiveRecord::Base:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rubygems

I have upgrade rails2 to rails3 and when i try to rake db:migrate I have found following error

```
`rake aborted!`

undefined method `mysql_connection' for ActiveRecord::Base:Class
/home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3214/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:55:in `method_missing'
/home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3214/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:315:in `new_connection'
/home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3214/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:325:in `checkout_new_connection'
/home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3214/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:247:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
/home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3214/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `loop'
/home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3214/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `block in checkout'
/home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3214/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:239:in `checkout'
/home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3214/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:102:in `block in connection'
/home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3214/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:101:in `connection'
/home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3214/gems/ar-octopus-0.6.1/lib/octopus/proxy.rb:153:in `select_connection'
/home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3214/gems/ar-octopus-0.6.1/lib/octopus/proxy.rb:215:in `method_missing'
/home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3214/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/migration.rb:662:in `initialize'
/home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3214/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/migration.rb:570:in `new'
/home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3214/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/migration.rb:570:in `up'
/home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3214/gems/ar-octopus-0.6.1/lib/octopus/migration.rb:117:in `up_with_octopus'
/home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3214/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/migration.rb:551:in `migrate'
/home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3214/gems/ar-octopus-0.6.1/lib/octopus/migration.rb:111:in `block in migrate_with_octopus'
/home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3214/gems/ar-octopus-0.6.1/lib/octopus/proxy.rb:171:in `run_queries_on_shard'
/home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3214/gems/ar-octopus-0.6.1/lib/octopus/proxy.rb:180:in `block in send_queries_to_multiple_shards'
/home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3214/gems/ar-octopus-0.6.1/lib/octopus/proxy.rb:179:in `each'
/home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3214/gems/ar-octopus-0.6.1/lib/octopus/proxy.rb:179:in `send_queries_to_multiple_shards'
/home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3214/gems/ar-octopus-0.6.1/lib/octopus/migration.rb:110:in `migrate_with_octopus'
/home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3214/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:193:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3214/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/cis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3214/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)`
```

here are my database.yml file 
development:

adapter: mysql2

database: db

username: root

password:

socket: /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock

Comment: Check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129644/rails-3-mysql-problems

Comment: Are you using 'mysql2' gem?

Comment: Thanx for reply but i already use mysql2 gem and the application running successfully but at the time of migration it give me above error

Comment: can you show your database.yml?

Comment: i have attach my db file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank's everyone
The error was resolve there is gem dependency issue 
i have use gem mysql2 , activerecord-mysql2-adapter , mysql so there is conflicts error instead of it I  have use only mysql2 gem change the adapter mysql to mysql2

Answer (score 0):

Include it in files that possess bizarre characters...

```
#encoding: utf-8
```

Hope this helps!